# Drying up/refactoring a component nin ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this long-winded component which is passing many props. Is there a dryer way of passing this component to child?

Thanks.

```
let products;
if (!this.state.loading) {
  products = this.state.products.map(product => (
    <Product
      description={product.description}
      title={product.title}
      originalRetailPrice={product.original_retail_price.formatted_value}
      retailPrice={product.retail_price.formatted_value}
      priceValue={product.retail_price.value}
      discounted={product.discount}
      imageURL={product.cover_image_url}
      key={product.uuid}
      uuid={product.uuid}
      onClick={this.addToBagHandler}
    />
  ));
}
```

These are properties returned from an api call.

Comment: You could parse the the data when it's returned and consolidate it into a single object called ```product``` or something similar. Looks like you're already getting an object like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just pass the whole product instead

```
let products;
if (!this.state.loading) {
  products = this.state.products.map(product => (
    <Product
      product={product}
      onClick={this.addToBagHandler}
    />
  ));
}
```

And inside `Product` you can access them like this:

```
const { description, title, discount } = this.props.product
```

Answer (score 0):

You can destructure like this

```
   let products;

   if (!this.state.loading) {
    products = this.state.products.map(({
    description,title, original_retail_price,
    retail_price, retail_price,discount,cover_image_url,
    uuid}) => 
    <Product 
    description={description}
    title={title}
    originalRetailPrice={original_retail_price.formatted_value}
    retailPrice={retail_price.formatted_value}
    priceValue={retail_price.value}
    discounted={discount} 
    imageURL={cover_image_url}
    key={uuid}
    uuid={uuid}
    onClick={this.addToBagHandler}/>
  )}
```